# UDP or HTTP over TCP/IP for a simple multiplayer game

Tags: networking, web-applications, tcp, udp, multiplayer

I am building a multiplayer game where players are simultaneously asked a question and they have to pick an answer. They have a few seconds to answer and they are asked the next question when the time is out or everyone has answered.

I am planning on using Java (or nodeJS if I feel like learning a new framework) on the server side and JS (jQuery and jQuery Mobile) on the client side. I might build native apps later too so I want to keep the option opened.

My question is: what server communication protocol would you suggest?

I was thinking of regular TCP (HTTP with Ajax) calls since latency is not really the issue but I am ready to review this choice if you suggest otherwise.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using UDP the burden to implement retry and congestion control will fall on *you*. Therefore, I recommend you stick with the reliable and easy TCP until there is a specific reason to switch. If latency turns out not to be acceptable, which I doubt in your case, you can switch to UDP.

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting UDP to be an overkill for such a low latency app but I wanted to make sure. You totally convinced me.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to remember, if you are creating the game on mobile device and you don't want to lose the players connected over 3G, you will need to make sure you are using standard ports to connect to the server side, otherwise operators will disconnect you.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Streaming and WebSockets over TCP/IP is the best way to go. Lightstreamer, which leverages HTTP and WebSockets, uses TCP but tries to overcome some of its limits with some smart algorithms for latency reduction (which seems to be crucial for the game you described) and bandwidth optimization. Thus, it can be used with great benefits for any multiplayer games of any complexity (including MMORPGs, for example). At a first glance it seems it can fulfill your requirements, and it could be a good solution if you are also planning to develop native apps in a second step.

Lightstreamer is based on a publish/subscribe model, in which every item is defined by a set of fields whose values can change over time (in order of milliseconds). These could include "general items", subscribed by any users (e.g the game countdown; who is the first responder) and delivered in real-time. This way, the data delivery mechanism underlying your game logic seems quite easy to implement with Lightstreamer.

Have a look at this recent article ([Optimizing Multiplayer 3D Game Synchronization Over the Web](http://blog.lightstreamer.com/2013/10/optimizing-multiplayer-3d-game.html)). You can walk through an online demo of a simple multiplayer 3D world in which Lightstreamer has been integrated for real-time synchronization.

The demo allows you to tweak each parameter of the scenario and simulate any flavor of data delivery, while checking the actual bandwidth consumption. Of course, full source code is available for free on GitHub. You could give it a try. Let me know if you need some help :)

[full disclosure: I work for Lightstreamer]